# .htaccess rewrite on a folder is affecting its subfolders too

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP file located in a folder ("www.mysite.com/folder/test.php") which accepts a get argument (str) and lets say print. in order to make the URLs SEO friendly I'm trying to rewrite it like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ folder/test\.php?str=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

the rewrite rule works fine, the problem is when I need to access the subfolder of that folder. for example if there is an image in test.php that is located at www.mysite.com/folder/images/img.jpg, according to the above rule it takes images/img.jpg and passes it to the php file.

how can prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Should solve your problem - this just makes sure that the URL being requested is neither an actual file nor directory on the server.

Answer (score 1):

When you tell it "any character", it thinks that you really do mean *ANY CHARACTER*.

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]*)$ folder/test\.php?str=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, i tried your solution but same thing happens , it doesn't read any the css,js and images that are located at /folder/css , folder/images/ folder/js

Comment: i think we should exclude the strings containing anything other than aA-zZ 0-9 and + and -

Comment: what makes it complicated is, the actual location of the file is the same as the url i'm using :)